# Javascript form validation not working, not sure where I went wrong

Tags: javascript

I'm really struggling to get my form validation to work. I'm very new to JS so I'm not sure where I got it wrong. I tried looking through but still couldn't figure it out. Please help.

Here is my JS

```
const fname = document.querySelector("#fname")
const lname = document.querySelector("#lname")
const email = document.querySelector("#email")
const password = document.querySelector("#password")
const phoneNumber = document.querySelector("#phone-number")


form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
});


    function checkInputs() {
    const fnameValue = fname.value;
    const lnameValue = lname.value.trim();
    const emailValue = email.value.trim();
    const passwordValue = password.value.trim();
    const phoneNumberValue = phoneNumber.value.trim();

    if(fname.value === "") {
        setErrorFor(fname, "This field cannot be blank");
     } else {
         setSuccessFor(fname);  
     }
}


    function setErrorFor(input, message) {
    const inputContainer = input.parentElement;
    const small = inputContainer.querySelector("small");

    small.innerText = message;

    inputContainer.classList.add("has-error");
}
```

Here is my HTML

```
        <div class="input-container-first-name">
            <label for="fname">First Name</label>
            <input id="fname" name="fname" type="text">
            <small>Error message</small>
        </div>
```

Comment: Share the error pls

Comment: You're not calling `checkInputs` anywhere. You should probably do that from your event listener.

Comment: What's the actual issue?

Answer (score 1):

It like Andy comment, you not calling `checkInputs`, make something like this:

```js
const fname = document.querySelector("#fname")
const lname = document.querySelector("#lname")
const email = document.querySelector("#email")
const password = document.querySelector("#password")
const phoneNumber = document.querySelector("#phone-number")


form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    checkInputs()
});


function checkInputs() {
    const fnameValue = fname.value;
    const lnameValue = lname.value.trim();
    const emailValue = email.value.trim();
    const passwordValue = password.value.trim();
    const phoneNumberValue = phoneNumber.value.trim();

    if (fname.value === "") {
        setErrorFor(fname, "This field cannot be blank");
    } else {
        setSuccessFor(fname);
    }
}


function setErrorFor(input, message) {
    const inputContainer = input.parentElement;
    const small = inputContainer.querySelector("small");

    small.innerText = message;

    inputContainer.classList.add("has-error");
}
```

```js
const fname = document.querySelector("#fname")
const lname = document.querySelector("#lname")
const email = document.querySelector("#email")
const password = document.querySelector("#password")
const phoneNumber = document.querySelector("#phone-number")
const form = document.querySelector("#form")


form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    checkInputs()
});


function checkInputs() {
    const fnameValue = fname.value;

    if (fnameValue === "") {
        setErrorFor(fname, "This field cannot be blank");
    } else {
        setSuccessFor(fname);
    }
}


function setErrorFor(input, message) {
    const inputContainer = input.parentElement;
    const small = inputContainer.querySelector("small");

    small.innerText = message;

    inputContainer.classList.add("has-error");
}
```

```html
<div class="input-container-first-name">
    <form id="form">
      <label for="fname">First Name</label>
      <input id="fname" name="fname" type="text">
      <small>Error message</small>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

in this code checkInputs are calling on your submit event.

Comment: Indeed. I did not (know where to) call the function. Thank you naxsi, it works perfectly!